# Objective-C how to call to outlet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, function

MainGameVC.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *questionBox;
```

MainGame.VC.m:

I am trying to make a function that will change the text of the question box and apply the possible answers to the answer boxes.

When I try to declare my function it tells me quesitonBox does not exist unless when I'm in `ViewDidLoad` then I can access it with `_questionBox` but I can't declare a function inside `ViewDidLoad`.

How can I declare this function and have the compiler recognize my questionBox outlet? 
I tried:

```
NSString * question1() {
    questionBox.text = @"ABC";
}
```

and

```
NSString * question1() {
    _questionBox.text = @"ABC";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access instance variables in a function. You need an instance method:

```
- (void)question1 {
    self.questionBox.text = @"ABC";
}
```

Also note the use of the property. Don't directly access the instance variable unless you have a good reason to.

To call it, use:

```
[self question1];
```

Comment: Could I also pass an UIimage through an instance method? Example:  -(void) gameOver { gameOver.hidden = NO; }

Comment: Sure. You can do just about anything. You may wish to study some basic Objective-C tutorials and learn about methods and parameters. BTW - don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you came from Java, or something similar?
When you want to access a property make sure you refer to `self` first and not directly to the property.

This is not ok: `questionBox.text=@"foo"`

This is ok: `self.questionBox.text=@"bar"`

If you access like `self._questionBox` you will be accessing the variable directly, bypassing the property, which is not advised by Apple.

Comment: You mean self->_questionBox. Dot = property, arrow = good old C-style instance variable. And you shouldn't say "not advised" - a developer should know what the difference is, and using an instance variable is _sometimes_ absolutely required.

Comment: And `self->_questionBox` can be written simply as `_questionBox`. You don't need `self->` to directly access an ivar.

Comment: BTW - your "answer" doesn't actually address the issue in the question. The problem wasn't with using the `_questionBox.text = @"ABC";` line, it was that the line wasn't in an instance method.